# How can I send my own response in spring?

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt

I am implementing Spring security with JWT in my application and when ever an unauthorized call is made it returns the following response

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
```

The response json look like below

```
{
"timestamp": 1497832267379,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/path"
}
```

Instead of this can I sent my own custom response something like:

```
{
 "code":401,
 "message":"The request is unauthorized"

}
```

Any help is appreciated

*EDIT*

I updated the code to below format:

```
 @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

                //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

                Status unauthorizedEntry = new Status();
                unauthorizedEntry.setCode(401);
                unauthorizedEntry.setMessage("Unauthorized Entry");
                Map<String, Object> unauthorizedEntryResponse = new HashMap<>();
                unauthorizedEntryResponse.put("status", unauthorizedEntry);
                objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), unauthorizedEntry);
                response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

My Status class is below:

```
public class Status {

    int code;
    String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Now I am getting a 200 response but nothing is shown in the screen. It is fully blank. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to override the response with a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: Currently I am overriding the commence method

Comment: Your new code is not actually setting the status. You need `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);` for it to work. You have to tell the servlet engine that there's a change in status, or it will just default to 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a controller advice

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class, DataAccessException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
    @ResponseBody ErrorInfo
    UnauthorizeExceptionInfo(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        return new ErrorInfo(req.getRequestURL(), ex);
    } 
}
```

and ErrorInfo.class

```
@JsonIgnore
public final StringBuffer url;
public final String ex;

public ErrorInfo(StringBuffer stringBuffer, Exception ex) {
    this.url = stringBuffer;
    this.ex = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

and when you will throw a new UsernameNotFoundException the controller will handle the response.

And I suppose that the exceptions are throw in your @Override public loadUserByUsername from CustomUserDetailsService if the password/email don't match.

More details here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work for you:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    // notify client of response body content type
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    // set the response status code
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    // set up the response body
    Status unauthorized = new Status(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                     "The request is unauthorized");
    // write the response body
    objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), unauthorized);
    // commit the response
    response.flushBuffer();
}

public class Status {
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public Status(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Note that you need

Comment: I am using jackson in the other REST controllers as `@RequestMapping(value="/path",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)` .But in this case it is not a REST Controller so how can I send as JSON response using Jackson

Comment: I added an example using Jackson.

Comment: I tried the sample and now I get a 200 response but nothing is shown. I updated the question code

Comment: If you're getting a 200 then it's not hitting this code.

Comment: If you do't mind Can you provide the whole code snippet which matches.because when i try it either shows nothing or It shows the same format(default 401)